# Canvas to SVG impmentation for binpacking algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I have a binpacking implementation using canvas. I am trying to convert it to svg output instead of canvas.

I have tried with [Canvas2SVG](https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg) but I am not able to get any output.

The below is the correct working code of canvas. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

I am bit confused whether all the methods of canvas are available in SVG drawings

```js
Parts = {
  init: function(blocks, canvasElement) {
Parts.el = {
  canvas:   canvasElement,
  size:     $('#size'),
  sort:     $('#sort'),
  ratio:    $('#ratio'),
  nofit:    $('#nofit')
};

var desc = '';

/*if (!Parts.el.canvas.getContext)
  return false;*/
Parts.el.draw = new C2S(Parts.el.canvas.width,Parts.el.canvas.height);

Parts.el.size.change(function() {
 Parts.run(blocks)
});
Parts.el.sort.change(function() {
 Parts.run(blocks)
});

var mySerializedSVG = Parts.el.canvas.getSerializedSvg();

alert(mySerializedSVG)

return ( Parts.run(blocks));
   }, 

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  run: function(blocks) {
    var packer = Parts.packer();
    Parts.sort.now(blocks);
    packer.fit(blocks);
    Parts.canvas.reset(packer.root.w, packer.root.h);
    Parts.canvas.blocks(blocks);
    Parts.canvas.boundary(packer.root);
    return (Parts.report(blocks, packer.root.w, packer.root.h));
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  packer: function() {
    var size = "1200x2400";
    var dims = size.split("x");
    return new Packer(parseInt(dims[0]), parseInt(dims[1]));
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  report: function(blocks, w, h) {
    var fit = 0,
      nofit = [],
      block, n, len = blocks.length;
    for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
      block = blocks[n];
      if (block.fit) {
        fit = fit + block.area;
      } else
        nofit.push("" + block.w + "x" + block.h);
    }

    return "Percentage of area utilized: " + (Math.round(100 * fit / (w * h))) + "%<br/>Total used area: " + fit + " mm<sup>2</sup><br/>Wastage area: " + ((w * h) - fit) + " mm<sup>2</sup><br/>";

    //Parts.el.nofit.html("Did not fit (" + nofit.length + ") :<br>" + nofit.join(", ")).toggle(nofit.length > 0);
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  sort: {

    random: function(a, b) {
      return Math.random() - 0.5;
    },
    w: function(a, b) {
      return b.w - a.w;
    },
    h: function(a, b) {
      return b.h - a.h;
    },
    a: function(a, b) {
      return b.w * b.h - a.w * a.h;
    },
    max: function(a, b) {
      return Math.max(b.w, b.h) - Math.max(a.w, a.h);
    },
    min: function(a, b) {
      return Math.min(b.w, b.h) - Math.min(a.w, a.h);
    },

    height: function(a, b) {
      return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['h', 'w']);
    },
    width: function(a, b) {
      return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['w', 'h']);
    },
    area: function(a, b) {
      return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['a', 'h', 'w']);
    },
    maxside: function(a, b) {
      return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['max', 'min', 'h', 'w']);
    },

    msort: function(a, b, criteria) { /* sort by multiple criteria */
      var diff, n;
      for (n = 0; n < criteria.length; n++) {
        diff = Parts.sort[criteria[n]](a, b);
        if (diff != 0)
          return diff;
      }
      return 0;
    },

    now: function(blocks) {
      var sort = "area";
      if (sort != 'none')
        blocks.sort(Parts.sort[sort]);
    }
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  canvas: {
    reset: function(width, height) {
      Parts.el.canvas.width = width + 1;
      Parts.el.canvas.height = height + 1;
      Parts.el.draw.clearRect(0, 0, Parts.el.canvas.width, Parts.el.canvas.height);
      var color1 = "#ffffff",
        color2 = "#d0d0d0";
      var numberOfStripes = width;
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStripes * 2; i++) {
        var thickness = 5;
        Parts.el.draw.beginPath();
        Parts.el.draw.strokeStyle = i % 2 ? color1 : color2;
        Parts.el.draw.lineWidth = thickness;
        Parts.el.draw.lineCap = 'round';
        Parts.el.draw.moveTo(i * thickness + thickness / 2 - Math.max(height, width), 0);
        Parts.el.draw.lineTo(0 + i * thickness + thickness / 2, Math.max(height, width));
        Parts.el.draw.stroke();
      }
      Parts.el.draw.lineWidth = 3;
      Parts.el.draw.strokeStyle = "#c0c0c0";
      Parts.el.draw.strokeRect(0 + 0.5, 0 + 0.5, width, height);
      //Parts.el.draw.fillStyle = "gray";
      //Parts.el.draw.fillRect(0 + 0.5, 0 + 0.5, width, height);
    },

    rect: function(x, y, w, h, color, id, name) {
      Parts.el.draw.fillStyle = "White";
      Parts.el.draw.fillRect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, w, h);
      //Parts.el.draw.font= (w/10) + "px Comic Sans MS";
      Parts.el.draw.font = "12px Roboto";
      Parts.el.draw.fillStyle = "black";
      Parts.el.draw.textAlign = "center";
      //Parts.el.draw.fillText(id + "-" + name + " (" + w + "x" + h + ")", x+w/2, y+h/2);
      Parts.el.draw.fillText("#" + id + " " + name, x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
      Parts.el.draw.fillText(w + " mm", x + w / 2, y + h - 5);
      Parts.el.draw.save();
      Parts.el.draw.translate(x - w, y + h / 2);
      Parts.el.draw.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);
      Parts.el.draw.fillText(h + " mm", 0, 0 + w + 15);
      Parts.el.draw.restore();
    },

    stroke: function(x, y, w, h) {
      Parts.el.draw.strokeRect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, w, h);
    },

    blocks: function(blocks) {
      var n, block;
      for (n = 0; n < blocks.length; n++) {
        block = blocks[n];
        if (block.fit)
          Parts.canvas.rect(block.fit.x, block.fit.y, block.w, block.h, Parts.color(n), block.id, block.name);
      }
    },

    boundary: function(node) {
      if (node) {
        Parts.canvas.stroke(node.x, node.y, node.w, node.h);
        Parts.canvas.boundary(node.down);
        Parts.canvas.boundary(node.right);
      }
    }
  },

  colors: {
    pastel: ["#FFF7A5", "#FFA5E0", "#A5B3FF", "#BFFFA5", "#FFCBA5"],
    basic: ["silver", "gray", "red", "maroon", "yellow", "olive", "lime", "green", "aqua", "teal", "blue", "navy", "fuchsia", "purple"],
    gray: ["#111", "#222", "#333", "#444", "#555", "#666", "#777", "#888", "#999", "#AAA", "#BBB", "#CCC", "#DDD", "#EEE"],
    vintage: ["#EFD279", "#95CBE9", "#024769", "#AFD775", "#2C5700", "#DE9D7F", "#7F9DDE", "#00572C", "#75D7AF", "#694702", "#E9CB95", "#79D2EF"],
    solarized: ["#b58900", "#cb4b16", "#dc322f", "#d33682", "#6c71c4", "#268bd2", "#2aa198", "#859900"],
    none: ["transparent"]
  },

  color: function(n) {
    var cols = Parts.colors["none"];
    return cols[n % cols.length];
  }
}

//var blocks = [{"w":500,"h":200,"name":100000},{"w":250,"h":200,"name":50000},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500},{"w":50,"h":50,"name":2500}]

//$(Parts.init(blocks));


Packer = function(w, h) {
  this.init(w, h);
};
Packer.prototype = {
  init: function(w, h) {
    this.root = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: w,
      h: h
    };
  },
  fit: function(blocks) {
    var n, node, block;
    for (n = 0; n < blocks.length; n++) {
      block = blocks[n];
      if (node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h))
        block.fit = this.splitNode(node, block.w, block.h);
    }
  },
  findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used)
      return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
    else if ((w <= root.w) && (h <= root.h))
      return root;
    else
      return null;
  },
  splitNode: function(node, w, h) {
    node.used = true;
    node.down = {
      x: node.x,
      y: node.y + h,
      w: node.w,
      h: node.h - h
    };
    node.right = {
      x: node.x + w,
      y: node.y,
      w: node.w - w,
      h: h
    };
    return node;
  }
}

function sortAllBlocks(blocks, type) {
  var func;
  switch (type) {
    case 'random':
      func = function(a, b) {
        return Math.random() - 0.5;
      };
      break;
    case 'w':
      func = function(a, b) {
        return b.w - a.w;
      };
      break;
    case 'h':
      func = function(a, b) {
        return b.h - a.h;
      };
      break;
    case 'a':
      func = function(a, b) {
        return b.w * b.h - a.w * a.h;
      };
      break;
    case 'max':
      func = function(a, b) {
        return Math.max(b.w, b.h) - Math.max(a.w, a.h);
      };
      break;
    case 'min':
      func = function(a, b) {
        return Math.min(b.w, b.h) - Math.min(a.w, a.h);
      };
      break;
  }
  return blocks.sort(func);
}

function getParts(blocks, last) {
  console.log(last)
  var b = [];
  blocks.forEach(function(a) {
    var c = a.dim.split("*");
    if (c[2]) {
      for (var i = 0; i < c[2]; i++) {
        b.push({
          "w": parseInt(c[0]),
          "h": parseInt(c[1]),
          "area": parseInt(c[0]) * parseInt(c[1]),
          'id': b.length + last,
          'name': a.name
        });
      }
    } else b.push({
      "w": parseInt(c[0]),
      "h": parseInt(c[1]),
      "area": parseInt(c[0]) * parseInt(c[1]),
      'id': b.length + last,
      'name': a.name
    });
  });
  return b;
}


function getConsumedPanels(blocks, panelWidth, panelHeight) {
  var leftOver = 0;
  var count = 0;
  while (blocks.length > 0 && leftOver != blocks.length) {
    var leftOver = blocks.length;
    var r = [];
    toDelete = [];
    //document.write(JSON.stringify(blocks))
    //document.write("<br>***************<br>")
    //var packer = new Packer(panelWidth, panelHeight);
    var bb = blocks;
    //var bb = sortAllBlocks(blocks, "max");
    //packer.fit(bb);

    var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>', {
      'class': 'canvas'
    });
    $("#canvas").append("<div><br/><br/>Panel:" + (count + 1) + " [material name] " + panelWidth + "x" + panelHeight + "<br/></div>");
    $("#canvas").append(newCanvas);

    $("#canvas").append(Parts.init(bb, $(".canvas")[count]))

    bb.forEach(function(o, i) {
      if (o.fit) {
        toDelete.push(i)
      } else; //document.write("Not fit");
    });
    for (var x = toDelete.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
      blocks.splice(toDelete[x], 1);
    }
    count++;
  }
  if (leftOver == blocks.length) {
    //document.write("Some of the parts size exceeds!" + blocks.length);
    count = count + blocks.length;
  }
  return count;
}

function abc(W, D, H, T, SHELF_QTY, DRAWER_QTY, CABINETS_QTY) {
  var p = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < CABINETS_QTY; i++) {
    var last = p.length + 1;
    p = p.concat(getParts([{
        "dim": H + "*" + D,
        "name": "Left Side Panel"
      },
      {
        "dim": H + "*" + D,
        "name": "Right Side Panel"
      },
      {
        "dim": W + "*" + D,
        "name": "Bottom"
      },
      {
        "dim": W + "*" + 100 + "*" + 2,
        "name": "Top"
      },
      {
        "dim": W + "*" + H,
        "name": "Back 1"
      },
      {
        "dim": W + "*" + D + "*" + SHELF_QTY,
        "name": "Shelf"
      }
    ], last));
  }
  //document.write(JSON.stringify(p))
  return p;
}

var w = 100;
var d = 200;
var h = 300;
var t = 400;
var shelf_qty = 3;
var drawer_qty = 2;
var sheet_dim = {
  'w': 2400,
  'h': 1200
};

document.write(getConsumedPanels(abc(w, d, h, t, shelf_qty, drawer_qty, 3), sheet_dim.w, sheet_dim.h))
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}

#unsupported {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #FFFFAD;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

select {
  width: 8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="packing">

  <div id="canvas"></div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Besides your code not working. Do you have a specific `canvas 2d` action that `svg` doesn't support?

Comment: I followed this here https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg

Comment: We don't do library recommendation, so I removed this part from your question. I also fixed the snippet so it actually runs. However, you don't seem to be using said library at all in your code. Fast reading both your code and their *readme*, it seems you'd at least need to replace `Parts.el.draw = Parts.el.canvas.getContext("2d");` to `Parts.el.draw = new C2S(Parts.el.canvas.width,Parts.el.canvas.height)`

Comment: And for the question *[are] all the methods of canvas [] available in SVG drawings*, which I guess you only asked as a rhetoric question, the answer is no, for instance SVG has no way to read its pixel content like ctx.getImageData can, nor is it able to grab a still from a video like ctx.drawImage can, but it seems all the methods you use should be drawable in SVG. (note that the inverse also applies, SVG is able to do things the Canvas API can't do out of the box.

Comment: I updated code as per @Kaiido suggestion, Can you help me out...